# how to add text to annotation symbol in map

Tags: android, dictionary

i have done a app in android on Map.i have read following two links to place markers on the Map.
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme.

But issue is "i have to add number in the marker according to the distance between two points"

how can i add number in marker? Is there anyway something like adding textview that displays number? can anybody suggest me and solve my issue?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to provide `public BalloonItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView)` with an image with the number in it. See http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/wiki/NumericIcons for a massive collection of such icons. This is honestly the easiest thing: the icon collection includes many colors and numbers up to 100 in certain colors.

The other option is to use a custom View, set the background to a base image, write text onto the View and then get a Drawable from the View: much more complex but also doable (see [How to retrieve drawable (picture) from a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374123/how-to-retrieve-drawable-picture-from-a-view) for details).